# Why Typescript cannot infer the type?

Tags: typescript

Here is my code:

```
type Type = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

type FooProps = { id: 'foo', foo: 'i' }
type BarProps = { id: 'bar', bar: 'am' }
type BazProps = { id: 'baz', baz: 'different' }

const FooComponent = (p: FooProps) => ({ id: 'foo' })
const BarComponent = (p: BarProps) => ({ id: 'bar' })
const BazComponent = (p: BazProps) => ({ id: 'baz' })

const components = {
  foo: FooComponent,
  bar: BarComponent,
  baz: BazComponent,
}

function getComponent(name: Type, extraProps: ?) {
  const component = components[name as keyof typeof components]
  return component({ id: name, ...extraProps }).id
}
```

But typescript complains:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

https://tsplay.dev/WJBMrW

I'd like to understand:

- Why is it happening? What is the explanation?
- How could I have the code working without relying on `any`, `never`, etc?

Comment: TS cannot keep track of "correlated union types" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). If you need such behavior you need to refactor to a generic indexing approach as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Using that technique with your example gives [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKbMKm). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate target. If not what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly my problem. But what if each props had different values? Let me update my example.

Comment: Then it would look like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wjlElm).  Does that fully address the question now? Is the example going to stabilize soon?

Comment: Yes it worked. thank you. please submit your answer then I can mark as resolved.

Comment: Tangent to the question asked: you can make the code in your example more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by defining an initial array of tuples containing the unique bits, then mapping it to derive everything: https://tsplay.dev/WGGM0W Such a pattern would reduce the effort required to extend it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't really deal with "correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). In order to verify that `components[name]({ id: name, ...extraProps }).id` type checks, the compiler would need to see `components[name]` as a single function type that accepts the argument you're passing to it and returns an object with an `id` property.  The function and the argument both depend on `name`, and the only reason the call is safe is because `name` is the same *value* in both places.  But the compiler is not tracking the value, it's only tracking the *type*.  Meaning that it perceives the operation as if you wrote `components[name1]({ id: name2, ...extraProps }).id` where `name1` and `name2` are both of type `Type`.  And that call clearly wouldn't be safe because `name1` could be `"foo"` while `name2` could be `"bar"`.  So the error message you are getting is essentially the compiler worrying about this possibility.  It sees `components[name]` as having a union of function types, and the argument as having a union of argument types, and the only safe way to call a union of functions is with an [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of arguments (see [the docs for calling unions of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)).  Thus the problem is that the compiler sees `components[name]` and `{ id: name, ...extraProps }` as being of *independent* union types, when they are actually *correlated*.

---

The officially supported approach to dealing with correlated union types is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  This involves refactoring to capture the correlated information in a single "base" object type, and then representing every operation as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into either the base type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the base type.  I won't go into the fine details of how that works here since it would make this long answer even longer. Interested parties can read more at microsoft/TypeScript#47109.

For your example, it could look like the following.  The base type `ComponentMap` holds this information about the extra properties:

```
interface ComponentMap {
  foo: { foo: 'i' };
  bar: { bar: 'am' };
  baz: { baz: 'different' }
}
```

and the type of `components` needs to be manually annotated as a mapped type over `ComponentMap`:

```
const components: { [K in Type]:
  (p: { id: K } & ComponentMap[K]) => { id: string }
} = {
  foo: FooComponent,
  bar: BarComponent,
  baz: BazComponent,
};
```

and then `getComponent()` needs to be a generic function where `name` is of the generic type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Type` and where `extraProps` is of the generic indexed access type `ComponentMap[K]`:

```
function getComponent<K extends Type>(
  name: K,
  extraProps: ComponentMap[K]
) {
  const component = components[name];
  return component({ id: name, ...extraProps }).id // okay
}
```

This all compiles as desired.

---

Note that if you don't want to start with `ComponentMap`, you can *compute* it from the type of your original `components`. First you probably want to rename `components` out of the way so that you can change its type later:

```
const _components = {
  foo: FooComponent,
  bar: BarComponent,
  baz: BazComponent,
};
```

Then you map over `typeof _components` and extract the bits you need for `ComponentMap`:

```
type ComponentMap = { [K in Type]: 
  Omit<Parameters<typeof _components[K]>[0], "id"> 
}
```

And finally you give `components` the proper type and assign `_components` to it:

```
const components: { [K in Type]: 
  (p: { id: K } & ComponentMap[K]) => { id: string } 
} = _components;
```

Now you can modify `_components` to add or change members, and the rest of the code should just adapt to it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-oggeF6zFIylMo9crhiuVzbVmtbSiQBw7JzoqAArkFwsBBFEoBrY5bw1yIAAPONBYQ8OCQYoZR5BGPiDkmtfAYiEfLiS3yxU0Ip8R7lqCVuZIV8nNmHiwN4lQQLAOOxA8h+wADKK34QDIAB0sFnhe+RbNBIg6jQQA)